# Game of Pig - can't figure out how to loop through all the players

Tags: python, while-loop, pygame

I have figured out most of the problem but can't seem to figure out how to loop through each of the players to let them play the game. This is the code I have so far. I think that my while loop in the main() function is wrong but I don't know what to do to fix it. Let me know if you can point me in the right direction. I also need to figure out how to end the turn if you roll a 1.

```
import random


def instructions():
    print ("==================================================")
    print ("\nWelcome to the Game of Pig.  To win, be the")
    print ("player with the most points at the end of the")
    print ("game.  The game ends at the end of a round where")
    print ("at least one player has 100 or more points.\n")
    print ("On each turn, you may roll the die as many times")
    print ("as you like to obtain more points.  However, if")
    print ("you roll a 1, your turn is over, and you do not")
    print ("obtain any points that turn.\n")


def num_players():
    while True:
        players = raw_input("How many players will be playing? ")

        if players.isdigit():
            return int(players)
        else:
            print "\nPlease enter a valid number of players.\n"


def name_players(players):
    count = 1
    list_of_players = []
    for i in range(players):
        name = raw_input("Enter the name for Player {}: ".format(count))
        list_of_players.append(name)
        count += 1
    print ""
    return list_of_players


def start_game(list_of_players):
    points = 0
    for player in list_of_players:
        print "{0} has {1} points.".format(player, points)
    print ("==================================================\n")
    s = input("How many sides of the dice do you want? ")
        for player in list_of_players:
        print ("\n{0}'s turn:").format(player)
        answer = raw_input("Press y to roll the dice?")
        while answer == 'y' and points <= 100:
            roll = random.randrange(1, s)
            if roll > 1:
                points += roll
                print "{0} has {1} points.".format(player, points)
                answer = raw_input("Press y to roll the dice?")


def main():
    instructions()
    players = num_players()
    list_of_players = name_players(players)
    start_game(list_of_players)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Well, `for player in list_of_players:` does in fact seem to loop over all the players. What the issue you're having?

Comment: it works just fine for the first player but if there is more than one player it just skips to the end of the game instead of letting them play,

Comment: Your main issue is that you're only using a single value to keep track of the score. I think each player should have a separate score, and you probably need another variable to track just the score they've earned so far in the current round (which they will not get to keep if they roll a 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you encountered is due to the local variable, **points**, in function start_game. All your players are sharing the same variable to keep tracking their score. Therefore, once, your first player reaches/passes 100 points, the game logic will move to the second player. However, the **points** variable is still keeping the score from the previous player (which is more than or equal to 100). Because of that, the following players will never get chance to get into while loop.

You should **declare points vriable** for each players OR **reset points variable** every time when points variable holds value is greater than or equal to 100.

```
def start_game(list_of_players):
    points = 0 #<----------------- points is local variable to the function
    for player in list_of_players:
        print("{0} has {1} points.".format(player, points))
    print ("==================================================\n")
    s = int(input("How many sides of the dice do you want? ")) ###
    # validate value of s?
    for player in list_of_players:
        ### the variables declared in for loop is unique to each player
        print ("\n{0}'s turn:".format(player))
        answer = input("Press y to roll the dice?")
        while answer == 'y' and points <= 100:
            roll = random.randrange(1, s + 1, 1) ### randrange 
            if roll > 1:
                points += roll
                print("{0} has {1} points.".format(player, points))
                answer = input("Press y to roll the dice?")
```

PS. I'm running your code with Python 3.6.1.

Furthermore, one more thing you need to take care of is that for `random.randrange(start, stop, step)`. The output **will not include** the value of stop. e.g. `random.randrange(0, 10, 1)` will generate integers from 0 to 9 inclusive. Therefore, if a player chose 6 sides of dice, that means the random number range should be from 1 to 6. In this way, you need to increment whatever number player entered.
e.g. 6 sides of dice
either `random.randrange(0, 6+1, 1)` or `random.randrange(6+1)` should work.